# Weird behavior when squaring elements in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sqrt

I have two numpy arrays of shape (1, 250000):

```
a = [[  0 254   1 ..., 255   0   1]]
b = [[  1   0 252 ...,   0 255 255]]
```

I want to create a new numpy array whose elements are the square root of the sum of squares of elements in the arrays `a` and `b`, but I am not getting the correct result:

```
>>> c = np.sqrt(np.square(a)+np.square(b))
>>> print c
[[ 1.          2.          4.12310553 ...,  1.          1.          1.41421354]]
```

Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: your example actually works fine for me. `import numpy as np`

`a = [[  0 ,254 ,  1,  255,   0 ,  1]]`
`b = [[  1  , 0, 252  ,  0, 255, 255]]`


`c = np.sqrt(np.square(a)+np.square(b))`
 Output: `[[   1.          254.          252.00198412  255.          255.
   255.00196078]]`   The extra square brackets are not needed, but I left them in place to show your code runs, at least with a short example.

Comment: Please always provide an executable example if you can (see [MCVE]) to allow people to run your problem right away.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably your arrays `a` and `b` are arrays of unsigned 8 bit integers--you can check by inspecting the attribute `a.dtype`.  When you square them, the data type is preserved, and the 8 bit values overflow, which means the values "wrap around" (i.e. the squared values are modulo 256):

```
In [7]: a = np.array([[0, 254, 1, 255, 0, 1]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [8]: np.square(a)
Out[8]: array([[0, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)

In [9]: b = np.array([[1, 0, 252, 0, 255, 255]], dtype=np.uint8)

In [10]: np.square(a) + np.square(b)
Out[10]: array([[ 1,  4, 17,  1,  1,  2]], dtype=uint8)

In [11]: np.sqrt(np.square(a) + np.square(b))
Out[11]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  2.        ,  4.12310553,  1.        ,  1.        ,
         1.41421354]], dtype=float32)
```

To avoid the problem, you can tell `np.square` to use a floating point data type:

```
In [15]: np.sqrt(np.square(a, dtype=np.float64) + np.square(b, dtype=np.float64))
Out[15]: 
array([[   1.        ,  254.        ,  252.00198412,  255.        ,
         255.        ,  255.00196078]])
```

You could also use the function [`numpy.hypot`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hypot.html), but you might still want to use the `dtype` argument, otherwise the default data type is `np.float16`:

```
In [16]: np.hypot(a, b)
Out[16]: array([[   1.,  254.,  252.,  255.,  255.,  255.]], dtype=float16)

In [17]: np.hypot(a, b, dtype=np.float64)
Out[17]: 
array([[   1.        ,  254.        ,  252.00198412,  255.        ,
         255.        ,  255.00196078]])
```

---

You might wonder why the `dtype` argument that I used in `numpy.square` and `numpy.hypot` is not shown in the functions' docstrings.  Both of these functions are [numpy "ufuncs"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html), and the authors of numpy decided that it was better to show only the main arguments in the docstring.  The optional arguments are [documented in the reference manual](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html).

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the detailed explanation! Would using numpy.hypot be considered more "pythonic" than the way I am currently doing it?

Answer (score 0):

For this simple case, it works perfectly fine:

```
In [1]: a = np.array([[ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
In [2]: b = np.array([[ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]])
In [3]: c = np.sqrt(np.square(a) + np.square(b))

In [4]: print(c)
[[  1.     3.60555128   6.40312424   9.21954446  12.04159458]]
```

You must be doing something wrong.